# NPE in Quarkus application with InfiniSpan cache and JPA configured as its persistence store

Tags: hibernate, quarkus, infinispan

I am trying to configure hibernate-orm as persistence store to InfiniSpan cache. I have CacheManager as below:

```
GlobalConfigurationBuilder globalConfigBuilder = GlobalConfigurationBuilder.defaultClusteredBuilder();
globalConfigBuilder.transport().clusterName("AetherInfini");
DefaultCacheManager cacheManager = new DefaultCacheManager(globalConfigBuilder.build());
```

And cache configuration:

```
ConfigurationBuilder cacheConfigBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
cacheConfigBuilder
        .clustering()
        .cacheMode(CacheMode.REPL_ASYNC)
        .persistence()
        .addStore(JpaStoreConfigurationBuilder.class)
        .persistenceUnitName("<default>")
        .entityClass(MyClass.class)
        .segmented(false);
cacheManager.defineConfiguration("my-name", cacheConfigBuilder.build());
```

It ran into an NPE:

```
ERROR [io.qua.run.Application] (main) Failed to start application (with profile prod): java.lang.NullPointerException
at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.FastBootHibernatePersistenceProvider.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilderOrNull(FastBootHibernatePersistenceProvider.java:165)
at io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.FastBootHibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(FastBootHibernatePersistenceProvider.java:61)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:80)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
at org.infinispan.persistence.jpa.impl.EntityManagerFactoryRegistry.createEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryRegistry.java:89)
at org.infinispan.persistence.jpa.impl.EntityManagerFactoryRegistry.getEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryRegistry.java:28)
at org.infinispan.persistence.jpa.JpaStore.start(JpaStore.java:100)
at org.infinispan.persistence.support.NonBlockingStoreAdapter.lambda$start$0(NonBlockingStoreAdapter.java:108)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1736)
at org.jboss.threads.ContextHandler$1.runWith(ContextHandler.java:18)
at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$Task.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2449)
at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1452)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

I have hibernate-orm configuration in application.properties. Therefore there is no explicit persistence-unit name. I found <default> is the name in Quarkus (?).

Can someone tell me what is wrong or point me to related documents?
Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately the JPA store has not been maintained recently, and will be removed in Infinispan 14. I recommend you use the SQL store introduced in Infinispan 13. See https://infinispan.org/docs/stable/titles/configuring/configuring.html#sql-cache-store_persistence for details

Comment: Thank Tristan for the update and recommendation.